# How to fix XPS 9700 Microphone? (Given audio is fixed)

Tags: linux, drivers, microphone

Thanks to driver makers, since PulseAudio 14.0 and Linux 5.10, according to the Wiki, speaker works fine after simply installing pulseaudio and sof-firmware.

However, I still found microphone not working.

The situation is

0: I have already installed pulseaudio (14.2) and sof-firmware, with arch linux of kernel 5.11.2 on device XPS 17 9700.

1. I am able to detect the microphone

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH cAVS [8086:06c8]
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:098f]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 228
    Region 0: Memory at 609b218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at 609b100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_sof_pci
```

2. I am able to select between microphones
   One is "Comet Lake PCH cAVS SoundWire microphones",
   and another is "Comet Lake PCH cAVS Headset Microphone"
3. When using the microphone, there is a microphone usage sign in the system tray
   (Comet Lake PCH cAVS SoundWire microphones)
4. BUT I still cannot input any sound
5. The situation remains the same when I use either built-in microphone or bluetooth device.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Sorry if this question is dumb. When it comes to hardware, I am totally unexperienced. This is my first time asking hardware-related questions, so if I am doing anything wrong, please comment, thanks.

Comment: Ok, here is what worked for me - ubuntu 21.04, specifically with a 5.8 kernel - install that with the mainline-gtk app. Then, reboot into the bios and turn the audio support off and on, reboot again and it magically worked. hth. Other kernels I found did not work

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it just toggling Audio devices enable through BIOS setup (disable -> save -> enable again -> save -> exit).
Fresh Ubuntu 21.04, 5.11.0-22-generic, no any additional configs/drivers/etc.

Comment: I do the same - but sadly I need to redo this every few reboots. Not sure why. Tried all the way up to 5.14 kernel and see the same issue